# Como regresar a la pagina origen despues de cerrar un modal

Tags: html, modal

El problema que tengo es que dentro del modal se procesa un form, este manda llamar a un archivo para procesar una lista de códigos leídos desde un lector de códigos de barras.  el archivo que manda llamar "actualizacionResguardo.php, realiza una serie de operaciones con los datos, termina y al terminar un ciclo se le añade otro archivo que depende de los mismos datos para ser procesados y mostrar una listas de resultado.

El form del modal es este:

```html
<form id="procesarActivos" method="POST"   action="actualizacionResguardo.php">
            <input type="hidden" id="Empleado" name="Empleado" value="<?=$numero_EmpleadoActivoResguardo?>">    
            <input type="hidden" id="Cantidad" name="Cantidad" value="0"/>
            <div>
                <table class="table table-striped" id="tablaAgregarArticulos">
                <thead> 
                <tr><th label class="input-group-addon" style="font-size:12px; background-color: #5BC0DE;">ACTIVO</th></tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody  id="contenidoActivos" >
                    
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCerrarModal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnProcesarActivos" name="btnProcesarActivos" class="btn btn-primary"   disabled="disable">Procesar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

ahora lo que pretendo hacer es que, al pulsar el botón del modal, procese el archivo : "actualizacionResguardo.php" pero que me deje en la misma pantalla que contiene el modal, donde se habilita otro botón para mostrar las listas, el problema es que al terminar el proceso me deja la pantalla en blanco si no añado el require o el include con el otro archivo que genera las listas, y si añado el require o include con el nombre del archivo previo donde se encuentra el modal no lo carga, cabe hacer mención que este trae un md5 desde que se carga la vista, incluí este detalle pero ni así.

```
include_once '/escanearBienesUsuario.php?numero_empleado='.$Pasado;  muestra la pagina en blanco y solo la impresión que puse de la variable con echo y los warnings o errores donde me indica que no puede cargar el archivo.
```

he intentado varias formas y nada

```
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'codificacion/escanearBienesUsuario.php?numero_empleado=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'escanearBienesUsuario.php?numero_empleado=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Gracias

Comment: En `include_once` debes especificar un nombre de fichero, no una URL, por eso te está fallando. ¿No sería más fácil y más fiable hacer una redirección con `header("Location: ...")`?

Comment: @juanrpozo Gracias por tu comentario, ya lo intente , pero no me carga bien la cadena convertida en md5 y por lo tanto si me regresa a la vista del html, pero no carga los resultados de la consulta en el datatable por una diferencia de 5 caracteres que le clava al principio de la cadena md5

Comment: @juanrpozo Gracias !!!!! ya me funciona!!! deja hacer varias pruebas y te mantengo al tanto.  Saludos y buen inicio de semana!!!

Comment: @juanrpozo Me funciono muy bien la recomendación que hiciste.  Gracias!!!  Saludos